# How to find several most frequent elements in a list

Tags: python, list

My program below does find the most frequent element in a list:

```
numbers = [7, 1, 7, 9, 2, 9, 7, 3, 0]
counter = []

for num in range(10):
    n = numbers.count(num)
    counter.append(n)

largest = max(counter)
print(counter.index(largest))
```

Output is 7 which is correct.

However, if I add another 9 to the list:

```
numbers = [7, 1, 7, 9, 2, 9, 7, 3, 0, 9]
```

which means there are two most frequent elements in a list (in this case, both 7 and 9 are found three times there, as shown above), it only prints one of them - 7 in this case.

Is there any way how to change my code, so that the output will be correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution that works for any kind of data, not only for positive integers in a range known beforehand.

We count using a `collections.Counter`, extract the maximum count which is the count of the most_common number, then make a list of the numbers who have the same count:

```
from collections import Counter

numbers = [7, 1, 7, 9, 2, 9, 7, 3, 0, 9]
counts = Counter(numbers)
max_count = counts.most_common(1)[0][1]
out = [value for value, count in counts.most_common() if count == max_count]
print(out)
# [7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for num in range(10):
    if counter[num] == largest:
        print(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby

numbers = [7, 1, 7, 9, 2, 9, 7, 3, 0, 9]

counts = [(i, len(list(c))) for i,c in groupby(numbers)]    
print(counts)
```

Comment: `groupby` provides runs of the same key. You could sort the list and then use this method. The output of your provided code is `[(7, 1), (1, 1), (7, 1), (9, 1), (2, 1), (9, 1), (7, 1), (3, 1), (0, 1), (9, 1)]`. You're also not addressing OP's question, just showing a (probably confusing) list of `key, count` without explaining how it works or what OP is supposed to do with it

Answer (score 0):

As the indices of the list `counter` reflect a sorted value list, a simple solution would be to take the highest index: `len(counter) - 1 - counter[::-1].index(largest)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way:

```
numbers = [7, 1, 7, 9, 2, 9, 7, 3, 0, 9]
counter = set([x for x in numbers if numbers.count(x) > 1])
print(max(counter))
# 9
```